# What is RSA key size limit in iOS

Tags: ios, rsa, pkcs#12

I'm trying to import PKCS #12 store with key pair and certificate chain. `SecPKCS12Import()` function returns `errSecSuccess` but items array is empty. So my guess is RSA key size limit in iOS because keystore has 15360 bits public key.

What are limits for RSA in iOS? I'm interest in link to official documentation.

Comment: Check this: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/kamtec1/2012/10/13/limitation-of-apple-devices-iphone-ipad-etc-on-use-of-rsa-key-size-bit/

Comment: @RahulTripathi I already checked that article. It is 2012 year and there is no links to official documentation.

Comment: 15360 bits? Seriously?